# mongoose to display ref object in json

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm new to mongoose, using the following controller:

```
const Creport = require('../models/creport.model.js');

exports.save = (req, res) => {
    const creport = new Creport({
        curso_id: req.body.curso_id,
        nombre: req.body.nombre,
        ....

    });

    creport.save()
    .then(data => {
        res.send(data);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message
        });
    });
};
```

in the creport.model.js:

```
curso_id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Curso'
},
```

this will create a json file like:

```
{"curso_id":"5b5a14e8ej1a18ac0b5e5433","nombre":"el nombre",....}
```

while I'm looking for:

```
{"curso_id":"curso No. 1","nombre":"el nombre",....}
```

EDIT:
using populate:

```
exports.findAll = (req, res) =>  {


         Creport.find().populate('curso_id')
        .then(creports => {
            res.send(creports);
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message
            });
        });
```

};

will output:

```
[{"_id":"5b5ce554967f6a36f0c84fe6","curso_id":{"_id":"5b5a14e8ej1a18ac0b5e5433","name":"curso No. 1"},"nombre":"el nombre"....}]
```

Comment: After add the populate the problem was solved?

Comment: no, the json output is not correct as I want

Comment: My anwser is helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For return the data in this format, you need to use the **aggregate** method.

In my tests, I created one course and one Creport and after I executed this aggregate:

```
 CreportModel.aggregate([
    {"$match":{_id:creport._id}},
    {"$lookup":{
        from:"cursos",
        localField:"curso_id",
        foreignField:"_id",
        as:"cursos"
      }
      },
    {"$project":{"curso_id": {"$arrayElemAt":["$cursos.name",0]},"nombre": "$nombre","_id":0}}
    ])
    .then(result=>{
      console.log(result)
    })
```

Result:

[image: Aggregate result]

If you want to add more fields in the result, you need to change the **$project** phase.

e.g

```
{"$project":{"curso_id": {"_id":1,"$arrayElemAt":["$cursos.name",0]},"nombre": "$nombre"}}
```

- **0** : means that will remove the field in the return
- **1** : means that will show the field in the return

Mongoose Documentation: [Aggregate Lookup](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-lookup)

Answer (score 0):

You could use **populate** method, if you read the mongoose documentation you will find there's very easy way to apply.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0):

**`curso_id`** is an **`ObjectId`**. The returned json confirms this.

The semantic is correct.

You should probably add a

```
curso_number: {
    type: Schema.Types.String
},
```